# Seeking Recommended ECIES Libraries or Contracts for Solidity Development

Tags: solidity

Ethereum community,

I'm currently working on a Solidity project that requires the implementation of ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme) for encryption and decryption purposes. I wanted to reach out to the community and ask for recommendations on trusted and well-tested ECIES libraries or contracts that I can leverage in my project.

I'm specifically looking for implementations that meet high-security standards, have undergone security audits, and are compatible with the latest Solidity version. Any suggestions or pointers to reliable ECIES libraries or contracts would be greatly appreciated. If you have personal experience using ECIES in Solidity projects or know of reputable sources, please share your insights.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecies-geth/v/1.6.11